# Is there a better way to check for each element in a dataframe that it is contained in a given string?

Tags: pandas, substring, apply, contains, isin

Let's say we have a dataframe `df` representing the activities of some people as follow:

| index | Mary | Tristan | Louise | Arnaud | Justin | Stacy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **0** | Engineer | Software Engineer | Rock Singer | Rap Singer | Lumberjack | Biomedical Engineer |
| **1** | Guitarist | Aerospace Engineer | Author |  | Figherfighter |  |
| **2** |  | Business Man |  |  |  |  |

And I would like to check if each activity is or *might* be software engineering. With `s = 'Software Engineer'`, we would obtain:

| index | Mary | Tristan | Louise | Arnaud | Justin | Stacy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **0** | True | True | False | False | False | False |
| **1** | False | False | False | False | False | False |
| **2** | False | False | False | False | False | False |

Which mean that I want to test for all cells in `df` that they are or are not a substring of `s`. What already works is the following, but it looks dirty:

```
s = 'Software Engineer'
df.apply(lambda col: col.apply(lambda x: str(x) in s))
```

What bothers me is the double apply, there might be a better solution right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check every cell in your dataframe if it is a substring of `s` no need to numpy, you can use [`applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) :

```py
df.applymap(lambda cell: bool(cell) and cell in s)
```

Note: `bool(cell)` is used to exclude empty and NaN cells and mark them as False.

Also if you want the other way around, ie. check if `s` is a substring of each cell, you can use vectorized string functions to further optimize your code:

```py
df.apply(lambda column: column.str.contains(s))
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the methods that you can do is using the properties of numpy arrays and then getting the appropriate solution

```
# Let's assume df is your dataframe which contains all the information
df=df.fillna('None')
# replace the null values as None
values=df.values
boolean_values=values=='Software Engineer'
```

Now your boolean_values array will contain the data in the exact format you want, and now you can just reframe the dataframe in the way you want

```
cols=df.columns
df=pd.DataFrame(boolean_values,columns=cols)
```

And there you go you have the desired output.